# How To Get Display Post Title Using Post ID from mySQL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am stuck on trying to get my PHP code to work. I can display the table for each user as expected with the code below. I have one field that is post id, and I would like this to display the post title.

Just to clarify, I'm looking at the edit in the h3 tags. the 'postid' is a column in a MySQL table. This is captured from a form submitted

```php
<div>
  <?php
  
        global $wpdb;
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
                                                                
         $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_test where userid=".$user_id." order by arrival ASC" );
        foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>
 <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
   <h3 style="font-size:1.5rem;"><?php echo $print->postid; ?></h3>
 </div>
 

            <?php }
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try the `get_the_title()` function here and it didn’t work? Or, have you tried calling `get_post()` on `$print->postid`?

Comment: hi @ChrisHaas ive just got it sorted. i jumped the gun after 2hrs of testing for help and than boom it works lol... i had the "$post_title = get_the_title($print->postid); // " put after the foreeach php closed tags not before it..

Comment: You should post an answer or delete the question. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: I have removed your solution from the question. If you want to provide your own solution, post it as an **answer**, do not add in the **question**. After a timeout, your can accept your own answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for letting me know. i will do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php echo get_the_title( POST_ID ); ?>
```